# Need guidance with structuring and storing Morris chart data with AngularFire in my Angular application

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, firebase, angularfire

I'm having trouble with how I should structure the data for my Angular metrics dashboard application.

I've been utilizing Morris JS' wonderful charting library and using the ngMorrisChart directives to allow two way binding with Angular.

Despite my research and reading I'm having trouble with how I should go about seeding, saving, editing and deleting the table data for these charts. I'm really lost despite all my reading on how I should structure and format then store this data.

The way I have this structured is a display view that has the graphs and on another tab it switches to a table view which I'm aiming to have the users be able to input the data monthly for example. Then we have multiple dashboards which would reuse these controllers.
FIREBASE JSON

```
"widgetOne": 
  "fa-icon" : "fa-area-chart",
  "labels" : "['2013 A', '2014 A', '2014 B']",
  "last_updated" : "2013-08-31T09:05:08.740Z",
  "position" : "one",
  "priority" : 1,
  "title" : "Title here",
  "type" : "area",
  "xkey" : "period",
  "ykeys" : "['Aold', 'A', 'B']"
```

**UPDATED CODE**
    app.controller('ChartsController',
        function ($scope, $firebase) {

```
        //Initiate Firebase Reference
        var chartsRef = new Firebase('https://dashboard-retro.firebaseio.com/lync/widgets/widgetOne');
        var charts = $firebase(chartsRef).$asObject();
        console.log('Here is the charts object ' + charts.xkey); //Returning as undefined
        console.log('Here is the charts object ' + charts); //Returning as [object Object]

        // set line, area, bar options
        var chartOptions = function(hideGrid) {

            // Need to pull this all in using firebase + $http
            var chartXkey = 'period';

            var chartYkeys = ['Aold', 'A', 'B'];

            var chartLabels = ['2013 A', '2014 A', '2014 B'];

            var chartColors = ['#c3c3c3', '#f36648', '#64bed8'];

            var chart = {
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                xkey: chartXkey,
                ykeys: chartYkeys,
                labels: chartLabels,
                lineColors: chartColors,
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                lineWidth: 1,
                pointSize: 4,
                gridLineColor: '#cfcfcf',
                hideHover: 'auto',
                resize: true,
                smooth: true
            };
            if(hideGrid) {
                chart.axes = false;
                chart.grid = false;            
            }
            return chart;
        };

        var  data = function() {
            return [
                {period: '2014-01', Aold: 4465279, A: 4932003, B: 187067},
                {period: '2014-02', Aold: 5005381, A: 4948005, B: 181611},
                {period: '2014-03', Aold: 5511556, A: 5423848, B: 223014},
                {period: '2014-04', Aold: 5387309, A: 5074078, B: 207068},
                {period: '2014-05', Aold: 6002556, A: 4733337, B: 330464},
                {period: '2014-06', Aold: 5309628, A: 4443538, B: 962987},
                {period: '2014-07', Aold: 5025872, A: 3831382, B: 1834638}
            ];
        };

        $scope.areaLyncOneOptions = new chartOptions();
        $scope.areaLyncOneData = new data();

    }
);
```

Comment: Waht version of AngularFire are you using? From your code it seems like it's pre-0.8, in which case I **highly** recommend that you upgrade to 0.8.

Comment: I'm using 0.8.2 but trying to follow the docs on their website.

Comment: I'd expect `$scope.charts = $firebase(chartsRef).$asArray();` in 0.8 and up. But I'm also not clear on what your question is. Is there an error when you run the code? Or doesn't it do what you expect it to do? If the later: what does it do? And what did you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm really having trouble with how to format the JSON on the graph data to store and read from angularfire. I wasn't even sure to store it as an array or object so I left that method out for the moment.

Comment: If you have a list of items and each has (at least roughly) the same properties, then it's an array. But your questin remains too broad to provide a definitive answer to. How about simply storing the data in any format that comes to mind and working from there? Once you encounter problems, you'll know that you've made a wring choice. If at that stage you're uncertain how to fix it, we'll be here to help with the more concrete problem.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen you're right. I started to input values and try to use them in my code. I'm having trouble using the objects in my code. I've updated the post with my new code and the undefined I'm getting in response to the objects I'm trying to pull.

Comment: Charts won't be populated until after the data has loaded from the server. this is an asynchronous operation.